# Error en servicio web: EJBTransactionRolledbackException

Tags: java, glassfish

Estos serian los log del server.

Log Entry Detail

Timestamp           15-jun-2017 17:02:55.849
Log Level           WARNING
Logger              javax.enterprise.web
Name-Value Pairs    {levelValue=900, timeMillis=1497567775849}
Record Number       1239

Message ID

Complete Message

StandardWrapperValve[app.service.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet app.service.ApplicationConfig threw exception javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Client's transaction aborted at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.useClientTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:357) at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.preInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:251) at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4524) at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1986) at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:210) at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy623.getExistencia(Unknown Source) at app.service.**EJB31_Generated__ExistenciasFacadeREST__Intf____Bean**.getExistencia(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6312.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81) at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151) at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171) at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195) at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104) at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387) at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331) at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103) at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271) at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297) at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254) at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028) at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372) at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381) at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344) at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673) at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167) at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201) at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175) at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235) at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119) at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284) at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201) at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133) at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112) at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77) at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561) at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112) at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117) at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56) at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137) at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565) at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Lo que te dice esto es "Como ha habido un error, vamos a anular la transacción y no tocamos la base de datos". Lo importante es saber **qué ha causado el error**, y eso lo puedes encontrar en el fichero de log. Incluye el stacktrace, y además **señala cuál es la línea que lanza la excepción original**.

Comment: Por cierto, el `finally` se ejecuta siempre, así que no tiene sentido añadir un mensaje de error `System.out.println("Conexion cerrada, ERROR    " + cn);`. Y usa `java.util.Logging` (o similar) en vez de `System.out.println`, sobre todo en entornos JEE.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, y realice lo siguiente: fui al servidor glassfish en la parte de los logs, y esto es lo que me dicen:

Comment: javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Client's transaction aborted at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.useClientTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:357) at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.preInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:251) at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4524) at

Comment: com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1986) at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:210) at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy253.find(Unknown Source) at app.service.__EJB31_Generated__DescCliArtFacadeREST__Intf____Bean__.find(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor160.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect

Comment: mejor edita la respuesta como he hecho yo... una cosa curiosa es que estés mezclando JDBC directo con JPA (el `EntityManager`); aunque no digo que sea la causa del problema igual podrías probar a comentar el código.

Comment: No te comprendo a que se refiere con comentar el codigo, cual parte del codigo?

Comment: 1. Está bien que pongas la excepción completa pero no machaques el resto (sobre todo el código de tu clase). 2. No sé que IDE utilizas, pero intenta que compile con información de debug. De esa forma en el stacktrace te saldrá en qué línea salta la excepción (más info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613535/does-java-have-debug-and-release-build-mode-like-c). 3. Me refiero a todo el código donde abres una conexión directamente y haces una consulta a BD. Como explicaba es raro usar eso a la vez que JPA; te aconsejo que comentes todo el código y que devuelvas un valor fijo para probarlo.

Comment: El IDE que uso es el NetBeans y yo le doy debug, pero como me levanta el url del Web Service del localhost no me da ningun problema ni excepciones, el problema se da cuando esta el war alojado en el servidor y uso la direccion del servidor ahi es donde se da el problema y lanza la excepcion.